# array indexing results in out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a 2D array representing a binary image.

I do:
`ndxs=np.argwhere(obj_img==0)`

to get an array of indices into the 2D image array that I can then use to replace the 0s there with `nan` values via:

`obj_img[ndxs]=np.nan`

However, when I do this, I get an error similar to this, `IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 22`

I tracked it down to the way the 2D array of ndxs is being interpreted in the `obj_img[ndxs]`, but I don't understand why.  If I instead do,

`obj_img[ndxs[:,0],ndxs[:,1]]=np.nan`

this works.

When I use `ndxs` as the index into obj_img, what is python doing?  Why is `obj_img[ndxs]` not the same as `obj_img[ndxs[:,0],ndxs[:,1]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy built-in `Fancy indexing` to replace all values when equals 0:

```
obj_img = obj_img.astype(float)
obj_img[obj_img==0] = np.nan
```

Note that you first have to convert it to float since `NaN` is a special floating point sentinel value

Comment: excellent.  Thank you. To get averages , standard deviations , etc, that ignore the nans, do I need different functions?  np.mean(obj_img) is including the `nans`.